# Method call in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to Objective-C and iPhone SDK development. I want to call a method in the same class:

```
- (void) setFilePath:(NSString *) p
{
  [self methodCall];
}

- (void) methodCall
{
  fileContent.text = @"Test"; //fileContent is a UITextView
}
```

If the property "filePath" is set, the method "setFilePath" is called. Then the UITextView, created in IB, should display the text. But that doesn't work ...

If I call the method directly via button in IB, then the UITextView changes his content successfully:

```
- (IBAction) clickButton
{
  fileContent.text = @"Test";
}
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks for your answers!

**EDIT 2: I solved the problem by setting "filePath" after pushing the view:**

```
- (IBAction) showFileContent {

FileContentsViewController *fileContentsViewController = [[FileContentsViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fileContentsViewController animated:YES];
fileContentsViewController.filePath = self.filePath;
fileContentsViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content from von %@", [filePath lastPathComponent]];
[fileContentsViewController release];

}
```

**EDIT 1:** Here's the code of my interface:

```
@interface FileContentsViewController : UIViewController {

NSString *filePath;
UITextView *fileContent;

}

- (void) methodCall;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *filePath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *fileContent;

@end
```

... and here's the code of the implementation:

```
#import "FileContentsViewController.h"


@implementation FileContentsViewController

@synthesize filePath;
@synthesize fileContent;

- (void) setFilePath:(NSString *) p
{
    NSLog(@"setFilePath executed!");
    [self methodCall];
} 

- (void) methodCall
{
    fileContent.text = @"Test"; // UITextView
}

// some standard methods

@end
```

... and finally the code of the method that sets "filePath":

```
- (IBAction) showFileContent {

FileContentsViewController *fileContentsViewController = [[FileContentsViewController alloc] init];
fileContentsViewController.filePath = self.filePath;
fileContentsViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content from von %@", [filePath lastPathComponent]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fileContentsViewController animated:YES];
[fileContentsViewController release];

}
```

Comment: Show how you are calling setFilePath:

Comment: The [XCode Debugger](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007057-CH1-SW1) should also be able to show you what the code is doing.

Comment: @JeremyP I call it when the property "filePath" is set. The property looks like this: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *fileContent.

Comment: @Michel Neeser:  When you set the property, you actually send `-setFilePath:` so your answer to my request is that you call it when you call it - not at all helpful.  I actually meant show us the method(s) i.e. display source code you set it in.

Comment: @outis Thanks! I see that I should improve my knowledge about the debugger in Xcode.

Comment: @Michel: there's no substitute for an interactive debugger when you want to know "what the ‡¿¢& is my code doing??!?" If you do figure out what is happening, you can post an answer to your question so that others can learn from it (just be sure to add the code that includes the assignment to `filePath` in your question, so there's enough context to understand it).

Comment: @JeremyP Sorry, it's my fault. I told you the property of fileContent instead of filePath. This property looks like this: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *filePath. I will post the source code of the method that set the property in my first post above.

Comment: @Michel: we want to see the code that includes the assignment to `filePath`. The problem is probably that that code isn't being reached for some reason. Knowing the name of the class would also help.

Comment: @outis @JeremyP: Thanks. I do not have access on my code right now, but I will try to debug in a few hours an then, if I don't figured out something, I will post the required code.

Comment: Okay, I didn't figured out something at debugging. I posted the required code in the post above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it looks like is that the `fileContentsViewController` created in `-showFileContent` doesn't have anything assigned to its `FileContentsViewController.fileContent` (or, at least, `fileContent` doesn't point to a UITextView that gets displayed) when `fileContentsViewController.filePath` is set.

You set `filePath` immediately after creating `fileContentsViewController`. If `FileContentsViewController`'s `-init` doesn't create an appropriate `fileContent`, then when `-setFilePath:` is called from `-showFileContent`, there's no `fileContent` to set the `text` of. If `fileContentsViewController` is a typical view controller, `fileContent` won't exist until `fileContentsViewController` is loaded, which (I believe) happens during `-pushViewController:animated`.

One fix is to override `-setFileContent` to set `fileContent.text` as appropriate:

```
-(void)setFileContent:(UITextView*)fileContentView {
    if (fileContent != fileContentView) {
        [fileContent release];
        fileContent = [fileContentView retain];
        if (self.filePath) { // if file path is not nil
            fileContent.text = ...;
        }
    }
}
```

Another other fix is to ensure you only set `filePath` when `fileContent` exists, but this is more brittle. A third is to set `filePath` after you push `fileContentsViewController`.

The way you would discover the cause during debugging is to check two things: execution ("Is the code I'm expecting to be executed ever reached?") and data ("Do the variables hold the values I expect?"). Set breakpoints in `-showFileContent` and `-methodCall` so you know that the methods are being called (which would be one reason for failure). If execution makes it into `-methodCall`, the problem must be something else. From there, examine the values of the variables used in `-methodCall` and you'll discover `fileContent` is either nil or not the same `fileContent` that shows up later.

Comment: Thank you for your precisely answer! I fixed the problem by setting filePath after I push fileContentsViewController. That's works brilliant now! But, if I would fix it with your "setFileContent" method above, when would this method being called? When the view loads and the UITextView is initialised? Thank you also for your tips at debugging. I found out that "methodCall" was called, but perhaps, as you said, the fileContent was not load at this point.

Comment: `setFileContent` is a standard setter, so it's called whenever the fileContent property is set (which is the beauty of this fix), including during `[fileContentsViewController  view]` when the subviews are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that `fileContent` has been set up at the time setFilePath is called? If you're trying to set things up at start up then it's possible that you're making calls before the views have been loaded (which the OS delays until the last possible moment).

You can force views to load by calling `[self view]` just before you try to access any of your Interface Builder views (NB don't call `loadView` - that doesn't do what you'd think).

Comment: Thanks. I "solved" my problem with "viewDidLoad", that works perfectly. But, can you make an example how to use [self view]?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that setFilePath: is not called that I would guess that your code looks like

```
filePath = @"some value";
```

when it should be

```
self.filePath = @"some value";
```

When using @property you need to use self.filePath to call the methods, otherwise you will just access the ivar directly.

Comment: setFilePath is called, that's not the problem. But, if I try to call an other method in setFilePath in the same class, then the called method isn't "called" (code is not executed). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

How have you define filePath property ?
I think that it is the problem...